# Trying to make an AngularJS function to DELETE a MySQL entry

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I've looked around, but haven't found an exact match for this, so here goes...
I have a simple HTML page that uses AngularJS to output the items from a MySQL table. But now I'm trying to create a function that, when the user clicks on a button, will delete the item from the database. Right now, however, the function I have does absolutely nothing, and I was hoping a fresh set of eyes could help me out with this.

Here's the relevant HTML

```
<body data-ng-controller="testController" ng-cloak>

 <table data-ng-init="getEntries()">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr data-ng-repeat="name in data">
       <td>{{name.id}}</td>
       <td>{{name.fname}}</td>
       <td>{{name.fname}}</td>
       <td>{{name.email}}</td>
       <td><input type="button" data-ng-click="deleteEntry(name.id)" value="X"></input>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here's the Angular controller I'm using

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('testController', testController);

testController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']; 
function testController($scope, $http) {

  $scope.getEntries = function() {
    $http.get('getdb.php').success(function(result) {
      $scope.data = result;
    });
  }

  $scope.deleteEntry = function(index) {
   console.log(index);
    $http.post('dbfunctions.php?action=delete_entry', {
      'id': index
    })
    .success(function() {
      $scope.getEntries();
    })
    .error(function() {
      console.log('oh well');
    });
  }
}
```

and finally, the PHP code

```
<?php

  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  $host = "localhost";
  $username = "visarts_testing";
  $password = "******";
  $dbname = "visarts_test";
  $tbl_name = "tested";

  //open a connection to the database
  $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if(!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  //get action from the controller

  switch($_GET['action']) {
    case 'delete_entry' :
      delete_entry();
    break;
  }

  function delete_entry() {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $index = $data->id;
    $delSQL = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = $index";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $delSQL) {
      return true;
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br />" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
  }

  //close the db connection
  mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

The index is logging to the console like it should, but that's all that happens. Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: is `success` or `error` being called after your `post`?

Comment: I just added a console message to success, and success IS being called. So I guess the error is on the PHP side....

Comment: What do you get from something like : 
`function delete_entry() {
    print_r( file_get_contents("php://input") ); die();`
You have to look in dev-tools or firebug to view the response.

Comment: Ok, so I added that to the function. Firebug found a syntax error it didn't like, so I fixed that. But now, still, nothing happens, although this is what I get in the console:
    POST http://portitude.com/tests/db/dbfunctions.php?action=delete_entry
{"id":"1"}

Comment: Although I see now that that message is coming from my app.js file, not dbfunctions.php.

Answer (score 0):

You must return response with error code (501). Your php code returns a valid response code. (200 - Successful)

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing! I don't think this is true

Comment: How angular knows what went wrong? I talk about angular, not php. Its a pattern web.

Comment: oh you were saying in order for `error` in angular to be fired, he needs to return 501 headers, I get it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your PHP `if(mysqli_query($conn, $delSQL) {` produces an error. It should be `if(mysqli_query($conn, $delSQL)) {`

note the double parens

Comment: ok, are you sure you are successfully connecting to the database?

Comment: Pretty sure, although to be honest I'm not sure how to check that programatically. I'm pretty new to mySql and php, if it wasn't obvious. I have another script which takes form input from an HTML page and writes a new line item to the same table -- everything is pretty much the same in what I'm working on now, same db, same table, the only difference being that I'm grabbing data to pass in from the angular script file.